# What causes ClickOnce URLDownloadToCacheFile failed during installation?

Tags: windows, clickonce

I'm getting the following error when installing my ClickOnce application via firefox. It doesn't happen with IE on the same computer. I swear I've installed it via firefox before. This is a Windows 7 machine.

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.0 {version}
Running checks for package '.NET Framework 2.0 (x86)', phase BuildList
Running external check with command 'C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEF1A.tmp\DotNetFX\dotnetchk.exe' and parameters ''
Process exited with code 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNetInstalled'
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer'
Read string value '8.0.7600.16385'
Setting value '8.0.7600.16385 {string}' for property 'IEVersion'
The following properties have been set for package '.NET Framework 2.0 (x86)':
Property: [DotNetInstalled] = 1 {int}
Property: [IEVersion] = 8.0.7600.16385 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX\instmsia.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'VersionNT': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX\instmsia.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'Version9x': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.0.3': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.0': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX\dotnetfx.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'DotNetInstalled' and value '0': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX\dotnetfx.exe' is 'Bypass'
'.NET Framework 2.0 (x86)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697211'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://croppy.lukehunter.net/download/croppy.application'.
```

The following is the howto from Microsoft, but this doesn't apply to firefox. There is no redirection happening either.

> If a user has set Internet Explorer
>   Advanced Security option "Warn if
>   changing between secure and not secure
>   mode" on the deployment target
>   computer, and if the setup URL of the
>   ClickOnce application being installed
>   is redirected from a non-secure to a
>   secure site (or vice-versa), the
>   installation will fail because the
>   Internet Explorer warning interrupts
>   it.

Answer (score 4):

**Internet Explorer** calls either *LaunchApplication* or *ShOpenVerbApplication* procedure from dfshim.dll behind the scenes, whereas **Firefox** plug-in (as well as a standard bootstrapper created by Visual Studio 2008-2010, which could also produce this rare error) uses a different, out of date technique to launch ClickOnce applications. (Note, that *LaunchApplication* requires at least .NET Framework 2 SP 2.)

To avoid such error one could redirect **Internet Explorer** to a deployment manifest (.application) and all other browsers to a custom installer (.exe) that would install .NET Framework if necessary and then call *ShOpenVerbApplication*.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after using IE to install, then uninstalling, I was able to install via firefox again. Odd.

Comment: Yeah, “Odd” just about sums up my experiences with ClickOnce as a user. For me it has just been over-complicated, opaque and fragile. Give me a simple .EXE any day.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Within the local distribution package CLICK ONCE a web.config file was generated on line clientCache that was the problem, in which altered as follows for CHROME and IE8 and now run the file:

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this and it to resolve it was to disable the firewall. I sadly don't know what Firewall settings it was, I just disabled the lot and it ran/installed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting firewall options on this issue, I found that my excutable was pointing to the IP Address of the Application Server. When I changed the site deployment and consequently the executable to the FQDN of the server instead of the IP Address, the installer worked first time.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution, on cmd execute setup.exe /URL=http://< Production  URL>/

Easy!

Comment: Please check your answer again, or provide additional details.  Following your 'easy' instructions resulted in a "'setup.exe' is not recognized..." error.