# Using rundll32.exe to launch a click once deployment URL?

Tags: c#, windows, clickonce, web-deployment-project, rundll32

I am using the following command from the command prompt in windows:

```
C:\Users\myusername>rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,LaunchApplication "http://ClickOnceDeplymentURL.application" NULL 0
```

but nothing happens? No errors or nothing. I expect it to launch the deployment update... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028342/113116) mentiones that `LaunchApplication` is only available since .NET Framework 2 SP 2. Try the `ShOpenVerbApplication` function instead:

```
rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbApplication http://ClickOnceDeplymentURL.application
```